# Getting error while creating a react project

Tags: node.js, windows, reactjs

This appears:

Creating a new React app in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\my-app`.

> 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

> 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   events.js:174
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: spawn npm ENOENT
>       at notFoundError (C:\Users\russu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\9700\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:11:11)
>       at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\russu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\9700\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:46:16)
>       at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\russu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\9700\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:33:19)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
>   Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\russu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_npx\9700\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:36:37)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)

PS: i have node.js, i have a path variable i have everything installed, why its not working while using create-react-app and npm its nort recognized, idu!!!!

Comment: so you can type 'npm --version' at the command line/terminal and get a result back? If not check your PATH has npm added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reload your PC? Here some steps which should be done to make it work:

1. Go to MyComputer->Settings->AdditionalSettings->EvnvironmentVariables
2. Find 'Path' in the list, click 'Change'
3. Add path to nodejs folder
4. Reload PC
5. Check in cmd npm --version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue, and this works for me.

1. edit package.json so the new version of react-scripts is "2.1.8"
2. npm install
3. cd my-app
4. npm start

   [Source](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6908)